# Prevent node xss sanitizer on specific post requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, nuxt.js

Context is a node express api, I'm using xss-clean on my main server.js file:

```
const xss = require('xss-clean');

// Prevent XSS attacks
app.use(xss());
```

Problem: I want to save rich text, but it's destroyed during sanitation.

I want to keep this functionality globally, however it prevents me from saving rich text via rich text editors on the front end (ie tiptap-vue). The text saved with editor contains html markup, which is escaped when saving to the database, and when pushed back out to the front end via a get request the text reads out with the escapes and the element's markup.

Is there a way to prevent this global component from working on one specific request, or specific data within a request?

or is there a way to un-escape it for use on the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply modify the middleware from your own node_modules folder, and in the source-code file where it begins to parse the request object, you could add conditional logic that checks if the request object meets the conditions you're checking for-- whether it's a specific request or contains the specific data within the request-- and then decide whether or not you use the sanitization function on the request object.

[Unmodified] xss-clean/src/index.js:

```
import { clean } from './xss'

/**
 * export middleware
 * @return {function} Middleware function
*/
module.exports = function () {
 return (req, res, next) => {
   if (req.body) req.body = clean(req.body)
   if (req.query) req.query = clean(req.query)
   if (req.params) req.params = clean(req.params)

   next()
 }
}
```

To

```
import { clean } from './xss'

/**
 * export middleware
 * @return {function} Middleware function
*/
module.exports = function () {
 return (req, res, next) => {
   if (req.url === "your route path") {
     //don't use clean() on request object OR you can store only the data you want 
     //in a temp variable to avoid getting sanitized, then sanitize the request 
     //object with clean(), and then replace that sanitized data with the data
     //in the temp variable OR as a new property in the req object
     const dataPoint = req.body.something.dataPoint;
     req.body = clean(req.body);
     req.body.something.dataPoint = dataPoint;
      
     return next();
   }

   if (req.body) req.body = clean(req.body)
   if (req.query) req.query = clean(req.query)
   if (req.params) req.params = clean(req.params)

   next()
 }
}
```

This is a bit hacky, but does the job. It's dangerous to not sanitize unless you know for sure it's not going to be an issue. You could also simply not use this middleware globally in your application, and use it only on the routes you want this middleware to sanitize.

Comment: My concern with changing the lib itself is that if it updates those changes could be lost, possibly without me noticing. What's the best practice (or decent) way to use xss-clean on routes only?

Comment: You would always be able to notice it because of version control-- that's if you're using good version control standards. You can also pin the version of the module in your package.json so it won't automatically update the npm module to the newest version. This shouldn't be an issue since you're not doing fresh npm installs on existing applications.

Comment: I've modified node modules before. It's not a huge issue if you really know what you're doing. And you can always use version control to revert back to a stable branch/commit. But I agree, it's a hacky way to do it, but in this case the module is so simple and small it's not too much of an issue. 

You could create your own middleware using their package/API in your own scripting file. And then adding your middleware function in the routes you want sanitized. I can edit my answer to show this if you're unclear as to how to do this.

Comment: It's really just one data point on one model that needs to not be sanitized. The only alt to your solution I can think of seems dirtier, ie removing global xss-clean and implementing on each and every other route, if there's no way to do it native to the lib. How could I go about finding the right condition to place in the "your condition" area of your answer? Example being a post or put on 'example.com/api/listings' or 'example.com/api/listings/:slug'

Comment: If you're not going to use it as router specific middleware, it will sanitize every single route before router specific middleware and before your custom logic in the route. So, unless you want to go back into the data and parse the data back to your liking, you should just modify the package. Just add in that conditional logic that checks the req.url to see if it matches that route > take that specific data point save the raw data in a temp variable > run the clean method on the rest of the req object, add back in the raw data back in its original location OR as a new property in the req obj.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering what this would look like. Would 'your condition's simply be the route? I'm not sure what hooks in there in that place

Comment: Noticed your updated answer, thank you! I appreciate your input here

Comment: Np, anytime, lmk if any issues come up.